# "as usual" vs. "as normal"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-order

Would it be better to say:

> Losing a driver's license symbolically reflected incapability to operate throughout one's daily life routine **as usual**.

or

> Losing a driver's license symbolically reflected incapability to operate throughout one's daily life routine **as normal**.

Comment: I think the sentence needs to be rephrased, it sounds very convoluted to me.

Comment: If you simplified the statement/s to read: *Losing your driver's license reflects your inability to conduct your daily routine*, you wouldn't need to add either *as usual* or *as normal* because they're implied.

Comment: You don't really need them since "daily" includes these ideas. You could say "throughout one's *usual/normal* daily life routine", but then it is easy to see the redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out which one to use by looking at the reverse statement

> Without my driver's license, my daily routine is not as usual.

Meaning there has been significant impact on your *habitual* daily life after losing your license.

> Without my driver's license, my daily routine is not normal.
>   Meaning your daily life has deviated from other people's "normal" life.

Comment: oh, so "as normal" is correct? I'm confused.

Comment: In your usage *as normal* = *as usual*, what *normally happens*